# How to get GitHub event payload by event ID?

Tags: github, github-api

I can get a list of public events for an organization via [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events-for-an-organization):

`GET /orgs/:org/events`

How to get an event payload (like [PushEvent](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent)) knowing its ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub API provides no way to retrieve a particular event by its ID.

Each event has a `payload` inside of it. For example

```
{
    "actor": {
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/240830?",
        "display_login": "sigmavirus24",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "id": 240830,
        "login": "sigmavirus24",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/sigmavirus24"
    },
    "created_at": "2017-01-27T23:50:12Z",
    "id": "5227100855",
    "org": {
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1782156?",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "id": 1782156,
        "login": "github3py",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/github3py"
    },
    "payload": {
        "before": "7d52c200d80d86f70fbda3e9ebf48060867f9f65",
        "commits": [
            {
                "author": {
                    "email": "sigmavirus24@users.noreply.github.com",
                    "name": "Ian Cordasco"
                },
                "distinct": true,
                "message": "Create test.txt",
                "sha": "a623ca5974523ec35fd83909dd99b220e498ef58",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/github3py/delete_contents/commits/a623ca5974523ec35fd83909dd99b220e498ef58"
            }
        ],
        "distinct_size": 1,
        "head": "a623ca5974523ec35fd83909dd99b220e498ef58",
        "push_id": 1525269783,
        "ref": "refs/heads/master",
        "size": 1
    },
    "public": true,
    "repo": {
        "id": 50486230,
        "name": "github3py/delete_contents",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/github3py/delete_contents"
    },
    "type": "PushEvent"
}
```

Is an event from a list after doing `GET /orgs/github3py/events`. If you look closely you'll see

```
    "payload": {
        "before": "7d52c200d80d86f70fbda3e9ebf48060867f9f65",
        "commits": [
            {
                "author": {
                    "email": "sigmavirus24@users.noreply.github.com",
                    "name": "Ian Cordasco"
                },
                "distinct": true,
                "message": "Create test.txt",
                "sha": "a623ca5974523ec35fd83909dd99b220e498ef58",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/github3py/delete_contents/commits/a623ca5974523ec35fd83909dd99b220e498ef58"
            }
        ],
        "distinct_size": 1,
        "head": "a623ca5974523ec35fd83909dd99b220e498ef58",
        "push_id": 1525269783,
        "ref": "refs/heads/master",
        "size": 1
    },
```

Which is the payload from the event. That's the only way to get that payload (from listing events).